Is it okay to ask for money donations in an answer?
This answer has both a BTC and LTC address and asks for donations if the answer helped. 
Is this acceptable? To me, this seems somewhat unprofessional; StackExchange is a professional Q&A service, and asking for money personally is... a little iffy. 
Thoughts?

Soliciting users in that manner is absolutely not allowed. The content has been removed. If you see solicitations of any kind on this site, the post should be 'flagged' for moderator attention and the content removed. 

Thanks for the clarification!

@Emracool That being said, unless I'm mistaken there's nothing agains putting a "tips" address in your profile.

@Lohoris you're correct, the guidance we were given by SE staff is that placing such an address in your profile is acceptable, but putting one in a post isn't. This is less about the fiscal aspects of such a thing and more about complying with the "no signatures" rule.
